# Handle regular expression based redirects without .htaccess

Tags: redirect

Is there a way to add a pattern of redirects to wordpress from a plugin?  I'm using a host that sets up wordpress for me and doesn't give me access to the file system, so I can't edit the .htaccess file.

I've found lots of plugins that allow you to list URLs that you want to redirect, but I haven't found any that let you insert patterns based on regular expressions.

Specifically, I have an "events calendar" plugin installed that had a page of events for each day (whether or not that day actually had any events).  A later release of that plugin, took those pages away.  Now they are all 404, when I would like to redirect them to the main events page.  They are all of the format:

- /events/2017-08-29/
- /events/2017-08-23/
- /events/2017-08-19/
- ... (thousands more)

How do I put in a single redirect rule for all of them?

Comment: Does "pretty permalinks" feature of WP can be enabled / work in your environment at all?

Comment: if you cann't change the htaccess how are you will be posible to implement code that "create redirection" ? you able to change (edit) code of you theme? add any custom plugin? any mu plugin? opt-in? any code injection posible? or even is it posible any plugin install?

Comment: I can use "pretty permalinks" -- I currently have the permalinks format set to "Post name".   I can also install plugins through the wordpress interface.  But I don't have any other access to the file system (like shell login, or ftp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oleg's comment made me think that I might be able to find a plugin that would allow me to edit the `.htaccess` file.

I installed the [WP htaccess editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-htaccess-editor/) plugin. and was able to edit the `.htaccess` file despite not having shell or ftp access to the file system. I insterted the following line at the beginning of the htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/events/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/$ http://example.com/events/upcoming/
```

Now my pages are redirecting properly instead of showing 404 status.

Comment: There is an easier way to do the rewrites. You can just use [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function to alter the rewrites. Please read the entire codex page to learn a proper usage, especially the "IMPORTANT" sections.

Comment: Wouldn't that API be geared towards plugin developers?  I have never written my own WordPress plugin before.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you don't have access to the filesystem. You could perhaps use the WordPress theme editor to alter your functions.php and make just a small change using the function I mentioned, but if you found a plug-in that works for you, you'll probably want to stick with it.